# how to reset a form value in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

for Example there is a condition and I wanna reset the firstName value to null or empty is there something like

this.modelForm.get('firstName').clearField(); ? or this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValue == "" ?

thanks.

#Code

```
initFormGroup() {
    this.modelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.model.id || 0],
      emailAddress: [this.model.emailAddress, Validators.required],
      firstName: this.model.firstName,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with `this.modelForm.reset()`. It will restore the defaulut value of your form. Aslo you can only reset a control with  `this.modelForm.controls.firstName.reset()`

Comment: but I dont wanna reset the whole form , only a specific one

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [reset](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#reset) to `FormControl`, `FormGroup` and `FormArray` since `reset` is declared in `AbstractControl` but each one has its own implementation.

In this case you can do:

```
this.modelForm.get('firstName').reset();
```

That will clear the value and mark the control as untouched.